# RegEx Ignore a commented line.

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to parse the following text

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Packages
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

set_global_assignment -name VHDL_FILE [file join $::quartus(qip_path) "file_1_test_1_qip.vhd"]
set_global_assignment -name VHDL_FILE [file join $::quartus(qip_path) "file_2_test_1_qip.vhd"]
set_global_assignment -name VHDL_FILE [file join $::quartus(qip_path) "file_3_test_1_qip.vhd"]

# Register Tool set_global_assignment -name VHDL_FILE [file join $::quartus(qip_path) "file_INVALID_test_1_qip.vhd"]

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Sub Modules
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

set_global_assignment -name QIP_FILE [file join $::quartus(qip_path) "module_test_2.qip"]
set_global_assignment -name QIP_FILE [file join $::quartus(qip_path) "module_test_3.qip"]

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Module Files
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

set_global_assignment -name VHDL_FILE [file join $::quartus(qip_path) "file_4_test_1_qip.vhd"]
set_global_assignment -name VHDL_FILE [file join $::quartus(qip_path) "file_5_test_1_qip.vhd"]
```

Using the regex:

```
(?<=_FILE).*"(.+)"
```

This also works fine and gives me all the file names in text above, however it also gives me the file names of lines which have been commented out.

I've tried to make a RegEx which would ignore this however I cannot get it to work.

This is what I've tried

```
(?<!#)(?:(?<=_FILE).+"(.+)")
```

Please take a look at the [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/yT0eF0/4)

Regards
Ephreal

Comment: Build a generator that gives only non-commented lines and work line by line

Comment: I think the problem with your RegEx is that negative lookbehind only works for the last X characters, where X is the length of your lookbehind string "#". So your RegEx would probably onky work if the # is right before _FILE. RegEx is really bad at excluding patterns from matching...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ignore commented lines, you have to start matching at the start of the line and match anything but `#`:

```
^[^#\n]*(?:(?<=_FILE).+"(.+)")
```

Or just

```
^[^#\n]*_FILE.+"(.+)"
```

Both patterns need the multiline flag `m`.

Comment: In Python, comments don't need to start at the start of the line. But I'm pretty sure this is much easier than anything else and should suffice most use cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with regular expressions, just add [**another lookahead**](https://regex101.com/r/rA7mK9/1):

```
(?=.*_FILE)(?!^#)[^"]*"([^"]*)"
```

---

In `Python`, this is rather simple:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'(?=.*_FILE)(?!^#)[^"]*"([^"]*)"', re.MULTILINE)
files = rx.findall(your_string_here)
print(files)
# ['file_1_test_1_qip.vhd', 'file_2_test_1_qip.vhd', 'file_3_test_1_qip.vhd', 'file_INVALID_test_1_qip.vhd', 'module_test_2.qip', 'module_test_3.qip', 'file_4_test_1_qip.vhd', 'file_5_test_1_qip.vhd']
```

---

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/nuLvJr).

Comment: That worked, however why the [^"]* ? the following works just fine (?=.*_FILE)(?!^#).*"(.*)"

Comment: hmm i may have a bit quick. it dosnt work, also your own results show that you still get the INVALID filename in you results

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the lines you target have always the same format, you can avoid the regex with a field approach:

```
def notcomm(fh):
    for line in fh:
        line = line.lstrip()
        if line.startswith('#') or line == "":
            continue
        yield(line)

with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for line in notcomm(fh):
        parts = line.split()
        if parts[2].endswith('_FILE'):
            print(parts[6][1:-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you parse line by line:

`^\w.+"(.+)".$` -> Get your filename in capture group 1

[RegExr Playground](https://regexr.com/5vmk0)

Edit: maybe you need to escape the " (like ") in your language.